# Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x039B6198>

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.x, pycharm

При запуске сервера появляется ошибка:

```
(test_django) E:\test_django\courses_django>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x039B6198>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "E:\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 442, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "E:\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "E:\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "E:\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 206, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "E:\test_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 119, in load_disk
    "Migration %s in app %s has no Migration class" % (migration_name, app_config.label)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.BadMigrationError: Migration urls in app lesson_two has no Migration class
```

**Файлы которые я редактировал:**
1) В файле settings.py, в `INSTALLED_APPS` добавил `'lesson_two',`.
settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for courses_django project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'p@8k2c(&6&2q-*ak+b6blic@$%%^%@-cckn^+(vp(sy9m60t@%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'lesson_one',
    'lesson_two',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'courses_django.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'courses_django.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

2)couses_django/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from lesson_two import views

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'', include('lesson_one.urls')),
    # path(r'^ admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # url(r'^', views.home),
    url(r'^', include('lesson_two.urls'))
]
```

3)views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Home page")
```

4)lesson_two\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home)
]
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46764994/5909792),

Исключение `BadMigrationError: "Migration *** in app *** has no Migration class"` выбрасывается, если папка `migrations/`содержит файл `urls.py`, который является не валидным миграционным файлом.

---

А судя по коду в [django/db/migrations/loader.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/loader.py#L117):

```
if not hasattr(migration_module, "Migration"):
    raise BadMigrationError(
        "Migration %s in app %s has no Migration class" % (migration_name, app_config.label)
    )
```

Отсутствует класс `Migration`.

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45586598/5909792), с ошибкой по теме, и примером класса `Migration`

---

Документация по миграционным файлам (на русском): https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/migrations.html#migration-files

Comment: спасибо вам большое. Проблема была в том, что папка `migrations` содержала в себе файл `urls.py`. После его удаления всё заработало.